# string breaks into single characters when added to a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a json file in this format,

```
d = {
  "allowed_langs": [{
      "langs": ["java", "golang", "python"]
    },
    {
      "langs": ["java", "golang", "csharp"]
    },
  ]
}
```

My desired output is to make a single list of languages that has all the unique `langs` in it,

**Desired output,**

```
languages = ["java", "golang", "python", "csharp"]
```

First i created an empty set,

```
allowed_languages = set()
```

I tried to do it using nested loop,

```
for allowed_langss in d["allowed_langs"]:
    for each in allowed_langss["langs"]:
        allowed_languages.update(each)
```

But when I print it, I get this,

```
print(allowed_languages)
```

**Output,**

```
{'t', 'j', 'g', 'h', 'r', 'o', 'y', 'c', 'v', 'n', 'p', 'l', 'a', 's'}
```

Can someone please tell me why it breaks into characters?

I also tried `list comprehension`

```
print([lang for lang in d['allowed_langs']])
```

but this gives me,

```
[{'langs': ['java', 'golang', 'python']}, {'langs': ['java', 'golang', 'csharp']}]
```

while my desired output is,

**Desired output,**

```
languages = ["java", "golang", "python", "csharp"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nested set comprehension:

```
d = {'allowed_langs': [{'langs': ['java', 'golang', 'python']}, {'langs': ['java', 'golang', 'csharp']}]}
new_d = list({i for b in d['allowed_langs'] for i in b.get('langs', [])})
```

Output:

```
['java', 'python', 'golang', 'csharp']
```

Comment: thank you. is there a way to also check if `langs` key exists before adding it to a list? because my actual json file is huge and some of them missing `"langs": ["java", "golang", "csharp"]` entirely.

Comment: @MaverickD Please see my recent edit. I added `b.get('langs', [])` in place of `b['langs']` so that in case the `"langs"` key is missing, an empty list will be iterated over instead, without interfering with the final result.

Answer (score 4):

Use `set.add` instead of `set.update`. `set.add` is to `set.update` as `list.append` is to `list.extend`.

`set.add` adds a single element into the set, `set.update` takes an iterable as an argument and *adds each element* in that iterable. And a string is an iterable where elements are the individual characters...

Answer (score 1):

Just change the update part of your code(3rd line).

```
for allowed_langss in d["allowed_langs"]:
    for each in allowed_langss["langs"]:
        allowed_languages.update({each})
```

Python's set.update splits a string into its constituent characters.
You can overcome that by asking python to add a set to the existing set.

If you want the set as a list:

```
[i for i in allowed_languages]
```

Source: [How to use Python sets and add strings to it in as a dictionary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654183/how-to-use-python-sets-and-add-strings-to-it-in-as-a-dictionary-value)

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me why it breaks into characters?

`set.update()` takes an iterator and adds all elements by iterating over it. When you pass an `str`, which is a list of chars, you're effectively passing it an iterator to a list of chars. So it just iterates over it and adds all chars to the self.

So what you want is either:

```
for allowed_langss in d["allowed_langs"]: 
   for each in allowed_langss["langs"]:
      allowed_languages.add(each)
```

Or

```
for allowed_langss in d["allowed_langs"]: 
   allowed_languages.update(allowed_langss["langs"])
```

Where `allowed_langss` is a `set`.